# Creating an indexed variable by concatenating 2 variables - php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query:

```
$analyse_ot1="SELECT COUNT(*) AS ot_count FROM first, base, users
WHERE base.base_id=$base 
AND
users.base_id=$base
AND
users.id=first.user_id
AND
first.$sub='OT'";

$result_ot1=mysqli_query($con,$analyse_ot1);
$row_ot1= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_ot1);
$total_ot1= $row_ot1['ot_count'];
$otper1=($total_ot1/$total)*100;
```

I will be re-using this code many times on a web-page and want to be able to run it as part of a loop.

I don't want to have to rename my variables each time (where $result_ot1 become $result_ot2 etc...)

I've tried introducing an indexing variable $x and then appending it to another variable name:

```
$x=2;
$result_ot.$x=....
```

But , it doesn't want to work.

Any suggestions? I have an idea that arrays might be needed but I'm concerned that the queries will be throwing up arrays and I'm not sure an array in an array isn't going to set my computer on fire...

Comment: use `${$result_ot.$x}`

Comment: I get a: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' error if I do that...

Comment: Why do you want to make so many variables inside loop?

Comment: Put the query inside a function accessible from all the project. In that function you pass parameters needed for the query, such as '$base' or '$sub'.
And in any point of your project, if you need the information that the query provides, you just call the function.
For example:
$varNewResult = myQueryFunction($sub, $base);

Comment: @stilts77 its ${$result_ot.$x}..use it..

Comment: Thank you Dhara... I did use it and it worked. I'd forgotten the $ at the front. Genius. Thanks again.

Comment: `${'result_ot'.$x}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint to use your query everywhere.

```
//declare this in a folder, 'functions.php', for example
function analyse($base, $sub, $con)
{
    $analyse_ot1 = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS ot_count FROM first, base, users'
        ." WHERE base.base_id=$base AND users.base_id=$base"
        ." AND users.id=first.user_id AND first.$sub='OT'";
    $result_ot1 = mysqli_query($con, $analyse_ot1);
    $row_ot1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_ot1);

    return $row_ot1['ot_count'];
}
```

And in any other place of your project:

```
include 'functions.php';

$total_ot1 = analyse($base, $sub, $con);
$otper1 = ($total_ot1 / $total) * 100;
```

I did not understand well the loop thing. But in order to dave your results in an array, you could just do this:

```
$totalCounts = [];

foreach(loop){
    $total_current = analyse($base, $sub, $con);
    $totalCounts[] = $total_current;
}
```

And you will have `$totalCounts` that will be an array of the query result that we find in our function. That could be a way of saving your results in an array.

You could do it associative also:

```
$x = 0;
foreach(loop){
    $total_current = analyse($base, $sub, $con);
    $totalCounts['count_'.$x] = $total_current;
    $x++;
}
```

So, if you now access: `$totalCounts['count_3']` you would be accessing the result of the query on the third loop, for example.

I don't know if this is your answer. But maybe it helped a bit.